# IPSEC over GRE tunnel on PFSENSE

Tags: pfsense, gre

I have two PFsense routers xxx.xxx.xxx.28 and xxx.xxx.xxx.27 and local networks behind them 192.168.110.0/24 and 192.168.111.0/24. The point is to set up GRE tunnel with IPSEC between these networks. Actually, the tunnel is already done(10.0.0.1-10.0.0.2) and ipsec configured. But here is the problem. If to check the IPSEC status in the PFsense web interface there will be NO traffic through IPSEC... Nor from PING neither from sending any files. The only traffic that shown here is the answer s at the traceroute. I mean if i will make traceroute from 110 network to some host in the 111 network then i will see only incoming 3 packets on the router at the 110 network. And i will see 3 outgoing packets on the router at the 111 network. That is all. The questions are:

Is the IPSEC over GRE working proper ? Why there is no traffic in the IPSEC status?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not have a rules in ipsec interfaces for allow traffic.
Under firewall rules select ipsec interface and try to add an easy role for allow traffic any to any fie each pfsense